# Win32_ComputerSystem is not working to fetch the username in remote desktop(MSTSC)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wmi

To get the **username** of currently logged in user I am using the below code. It is working perfectly.

But when I run this same code in RDP machine (remotely logged in to another machine using mstsc) it will return **empty**.

I don't  want to use environment variable's username because it will give **XYZ** username when I do RUNAS admin with **XYZ** user.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

Comment: seems like this question was asked previously...

Comment: What's wrong with `Environment.Username`?

Comment: When you do RunAs user/administrator then give XYZ credential then Environment.UserName gives this XYZ  instead of who has actually logged in.